# Ruby on Rails - macOS Sonoma - Apple Silicon M1 Pro `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-silicon, macos-sonoma

Unable to "Get Started with Rails" on macOS Sonoma - Apple Silicon M1 Pro.

Creating a New Rails Project

Before installing Rails, checked to make sure that the system has the proper prerequisites installed. These include:

- Ruby
- SQLite3
- Rails, using the gem install command provided by RubyGems.

Please refer to the following terminal output for details:

```
Last login: Thu Nov  9 02:52:29 on ttys000
% sw_vers  
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.0
BuildVersion:       23A344
% arch
arm64
% ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin23]
% gem -v
3.4.21
% rails -v
Rails 7.1.1
% cd /Users/macosm1apple/Desktop/Working/RubyonRails/Ruby3.2.2Rails7.1.1 
% rails new blog
/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:66:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:66:in `block in exec_app'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:48:in `loop'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:48:in `exec_app'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/rails:25:in `load'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/rails:25:in `<main>'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
%gem install cocoapods
Fetching nanaimo-0.3.0.gem
Fetching xcodeproj-1.23.0.gem
Fetching nap-1.1.0.gem
Fetching claide-1.1.0.gem
Fetching CFPropertyList-3.0.6.gem
Fetching ruby-macho-2.5.1.gem
Fetching colored2-3.1.2.gem
Fetching atomos-0.1.3.gem
Fetching molinillo-0.8.0.gem
Fetching gh_inspector-1.1.3.gem
Fetching fourflusher-2.3.1.gem
Fetching escape-0.0.4.gem
Fetching cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gem
Fetching netrc-0.11.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-search-1.0.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-2.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5.gem
Fetching ffi-1.16.3.gem
Fetching ethon-0.16.0.gem
Fetching typhoeus-1.4.0.gem
Fetching public_suffix-4.0.7.gem
Fetching fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.14.2.gem
Fetching httpclient-2.8.3.gem
Fetching algoliasearch-1.27.5.gem
Fetching addressable-2.8.5.gem
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.14.2.gem
Successfully installed nanaimo-0.3.0
Successfully installed colored2-3.1.2
Successfully installed claide-1.1.0
Successfully installed CFPropertyList-3.0.6
Successfully installed atomos-0.1.3
Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.23.0
Successfully installed ruby-macho-2.5.1
Successfully installed nap-1.1.0
Successfully installed molinillo-0.8.0
Successfully installed gh_inspector-1.1.3
Successfully installed fourflusher-2.3.1
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-2.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.16.3
Successfully installed ethon-0.16.0
Successfully installed typhoeus-1.4.0
Successfully installed public_suffix-4.0.7
Successfully installed fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Successfully installed httpclient-2.8.3
A new major version is available for Algolia! Please now use the https://rubygems.org/gems/algolia gem to get the latest features.
Successfully installed algoliasearch-1.27.5
Successfully installed addressable-2.8.5
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.14.2
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.14.2
Parsing documentation for nanaimo-0.3.0
Installing ri documentation for nanaimo-0.3.0
Parsing documentation for colored2-3.1.2
Installing ri documentation for colored2-3.1.2
Parsing documentation for claide-1.1.0
Installing ri documentation for claide-1.1.0
Parsing documentation for CFPropertyList-3.0.6
Installing ri documentation for CFPropertyList-3.0.6
Parsing documentation for atomos-0.1.3
Installing ri documentation for atomos-0.1.3
Parsing documentation for xcodeproj-1.23.0
Installing ri documentation for xcodeproj-1.23.0
Parsing documentation for ruby-macho-2.5.1
Installing ri documentation for ruby-macho-2.5.1
Parsing documentation for nap-1.1.0
Installing ri documentation for nap-1.1.0
Parsing documentation for molinillo-0.8.0
Installing ri documentation for molinillo-0.8.0
Parsing documentation for gh_inspector-1.1.3
Installing ri documentation for gh_inspector-1.1.3
Parsing documentation for fourflusher-2.3.1
Installing ri documentation for fourflusher-2.3.1
Parsing documentation for escape-0.0.4
Installing ri documentation for escape-0.0.4
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Parsing documentation for netrc-0.11.0
Installing ri documentation for netrc-0.11.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-search-1.0.1
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-search-1.0.1
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-downloader-2.0
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-downloader-2.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.16.3
Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.16.3
Parsing documentation for ethon-0.16.0
Installing ri documentation for ethon-0.16.0
Parsing documentation for typhoeus-1.4.0
Installing ri documentation for typhoeus-1.4.0
Parsing documentation for public_suffix-4.0.7
Installing ri documentation for public_suffix-4.0.7
Parsing documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Installing ri documentation for fuzzy_match-2.0.4
Parsing documentation for httpclient-2.8.3
Installing ri documentation for httpclient-2.8.3
Parsing documentation for algoliasearch-1.27.5
Installing ri documentation for algoliasearch-1.27.5
Parsing documentation for addressable-2.8.5
Installing ri documentation for addressable-2.8.5
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-1.14.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-1.14.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.14.2
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.14.2
Done installing documentation for nanaimo, colored2, claide, CFPropertyList, atomos, xcodeproj, ruby-macho, nap, molinillo, gh_inspector, fourflusher, escape, cocoapods-try, netrc, cocoapods-trunk, cocoapods-search, cocoapods-plugins, cocoapods-downloader, cocoapods-deintegrate, ffi, ethon, typhoeus, public_suffix, fuzzy_match, httpclient, algoliasearch, addressable, cocoapods-core, cocoapods after 5 seconds
29 gems installed
%which pod
/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/pod
%rails new blog       
/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:66:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:66:in `block in exec_app'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:48:in `loop'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:48:in `exec_app'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:86:in `require'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/railties-7.1.1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/rails:25:in `load'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/rails:25:in `<main>'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    from /Users/macosm1apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
%
```

Comment: This looks like a permissions problem in that directory. Did you `sudo` create it, perhaps? Does this problem happen in any other directory? Try in a scratch directory like `mkdir ~/rails-test; cd ~/rails-test; rails new rails_test`

Comment: It works only in directories under~/, like .nvm .mpm .mvn .gradle  .nuget .kube .minikube .docker?

Comment: You have some kind of permission issue if that's the case. Try creating files with other tools like `touch`, `mkdir`, etc. Look more closely with `ls -l` to check ownership and directory flags.